# Set SetThreadAffinityMask greater that number of processors

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

Who knows, what will be, if I set SetThreadAffinityMask for example 0x00000002, and program will run onto PC with only one CPU? I didn't find about that moment on literature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system ignores any bits that do not correspond to processors.  For your example, therefore, you are attempting to set the thread to have affinity with none of the available processors in the process affinity mask and the call to `SetThreadAffinityMask` fails.

Comment: The docs are sketchy but my assumption is that in this instance the thread continues to run with its last valid thread affinity. There's nothing to suggest more wacky behaviour than that imo.

Comment: @Steve That's the only thing that makes sense. If an attempt to modify the affinity mask fails, then surely it remains unchanged!

Comment: @Alecs As I understand it, @Steve means the value of the thread affinity as it was before the call to `SetThreadAffinityMask`.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant.  Even if you make multiple failed calls, the last valid value would be used to ensure continued operation of the thread.

Comment: @David @Steve so as I understand setting ThreadAffinity to 5, for example, in equal in most cases(not much PC now have more than 4  kernels in their CPU) just not to call SetThreadAffinityMask?

Comment: @Alecs What are you trying to achieve?  Why are you modifying affinity?

Comment: @David there are several threads, one of them is very hard, others are told to work on zero(first) kernel, if there are more than one the hard one will use others. Sorry my English

Comment: @Alecs if you want to affinitise threads then you should call GetProcessAffinityMask to work out what processors are available. Then you don't need to hard code any values.